# AWS EC2 Instance Virtual Machine having RDP connection & network issue

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, amazon-web-services

On AWS, we have an EC2 instance -- a **Windows 2019** Virtual Machine. This VM is created in a non-domain standalone VM with **Public IP** (enabled).

After successfully creating it, when I try to RDP from my laptop I get this familiar error.

1. Remote access to the server is not enabled
2. Remote machine is turned off
3. remote computer is not available on the network.

This is a new VM created a few minutes ago with my home IP added to the **Security Groups**. Also, right after creation, obtained the administrator password using the private key. The first attempt to RDP to this machine throws this error.

When I try to ping from my laptop using this command `ping -a PublicIP`, I get the full name with `*.compute-1.amazonaws.com`, but the ping fails with request timeout. That leads me to believe that DNS works, but not connection to it.

How do I establish a successful RDP connection.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out in AWS EC2 instances, when a public IP is chosen, we need to create a `custom routing table` allowing traffic to this new VM.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html#Add_IGW_Routing

This trick made it work!! Phew!!

Comment: This means that you created your instance in a private subnet. You should have created it in a public subnet which already have a route to Internet (through Internet gateway)

Comment: @Algeriassic -- interesting !! I'll try that and see how it works ! Thanks for sharing your insight!